# Is there a way to execute some code when a promise is fulfilled, independently from the outcome?

Tags: javascript, promise

I need to execute the `go()` method when the promise is fulfilled, even if there is an error. (I am talking to backend API, and I need to do some UI work when I have the server response, even if is a 404).

Now I do this way:

```
Try.method().then(()=>{
  go();
}).catch({
  go();
})
```

There is a better way to avoid repeating the method invocation?

Comment: Are you asking about a particular promise implementation or the ES6 standard ones?

Answer (score 2):

There is a `finally()` callback which will be called no matter what the outcome is:

```
Try.method().then(()=>{
  go();
}).catch({
  go();
}).finally({
  go();
});
```

Since you are using babeljs which doesn't appear to support the `finally()` callback you can probably get away with this:

```
Try.method().catch(()=>{
  go();
}).then({
  go();
})
```

Where you first catch an error if there is one, if not it will execute the `.then()` as usual.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be called in my code

Comment: @ciaoben This is the way to do something regardless of the outcome. Could you provide a plunkr that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I am using babeljs, and it says me that is not a method

Comment: @ciaoben That would explain it, should probably put that as a tag.

Comment: I was thinking that since every promise callback is chainable, I have added a new `.then()` and it seems to do the job

Comment: @ciaoben Check my updated answer for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a better way to avoid repeating the method invocation?

Not certain if interpret above portion of Question correctly ? Try defining a separate `.then(go, go)` chained to end of api calls

```js
var go = function(data) {
  console.log("go", data)
};

var p = function(args, val) {
  return Promise[args](val)
};

p("resolve", 1).then(go, go);

p("reject", 0).then(go, go);
```

---

If can use jQuery, could try utilizing [`deferred.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always)

```js
var go = function(data) {
  console.log("go", data)
};

var p = function(args, val) {
  return $.Deferred()[args](val)
};

p("resolve", 1).always(go);

p("reject", 0).always(go);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```